# Asynchronous message queues and processing like Amazon Simple Queue service in django

Tags: django, asynchronous, message-queue, rabbitmq, celery

There are many activities on an application that need things like:

- Send email, Post to twitter
- thumbnail an image, into several sizes
- call a cron to find connected relationships

A good way to do these tasks is to write into an asynchronous queue on which operations are performed.

What django application can be used to implement such functionality, as the one Amazon Simple Queue service offers, locally?

I have come across [celery](http://celeryproject.org/). Right thing? Anything else that exists, like this?

Comment: celery definitely does what you describe, but I'm biased. Here's a good tutorial: http://mathematism.com/2010/feb/16/message-queues-django-and-celery-quick-start/

Answer (score 1):

[Beanstalkd](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/) can also do what you want, and I've used it (though not from Python) to do some similar things (resizing images, and running other background tasks). There are a couple of Python client libraries to interface with it.